# how to include php function with parameters in Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

Hey everyone can any one tell me how to include php function in jquery-json/ajax my code

```
          php: get_bus_sched($origin, $destination)

        ###########jquery##########################
        var origz = "<?php echo $_POST['org_id']; ?>"
        var odesz = "<?php echo $_POST['des_id']; ?>"
        var theme = "";
        var source =
        {
            datatype: "json",
            datafields: [
                { name: 'sched_id' },
                { name: 'dtime' },
                { name: 'aday'},
                { name: 'atime'},
                { name: 'ttime'},
                { name: 'tdist'}, 
               ],
            id: 'id',
            url: 'bus_sched.php'
        };
```

How can I call php function ---> get_bus_sched($origin, $destination)

Comment: Use AJAX http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Comment: JavaScript runs in the browser, whereas PHP runs on the server. So you cannot directly call functions between them. You might want to look into AJAX, however.

Comment: @str but is it possible :(

Comment: sure it's possible but try to learn yourself

Comment: @edwardmp im reading it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you can mix php and JavaScript together in one file, it's important to realise that the php runs on the server during a http request and the JavaScript runs in the browser between requests.

With that in mind, it becomes clear that you need to make a new http request from your page to call the php.  In more detail this requires you to create a php script that calls your get_bus_sched function.  The script will need to get any required parameter values from post data.  You can use the json_encode function to encode the result then echo it out to the browser.

On the client side you'll need to write some JavaScript to make a request to the server containing the necessary parameters and write an on success function to process the results.

The jquery docs have good explanations of how to make an Ajax request.  The server side code will depend a little on what framework you're using. From you example code it doesn't look like you are using a framework so it should be reasonably straightforward.  Just be sure to validate you post data to protect against various security issues.

Comment: i had no problem with get_bus_sched function yap i use json_encode but in my jquery, i dont know where to put the get_bus_sched in URL: ? n how to include the bus_sched.php (get_bus_sched)

Comment: You can't include the php file.  You must create a php script to include it and call the function.  The URL for the Ajax request is the URL of that php script.

Comment: inside bus_sched.php is function get_bus_sched($origin, $destination) i dont know how to call that function inside jquery :(

Comment: As I said above, you can't include and call a PHP function directly from Javascript/jQuery.  What you must do is create a script that you can send a HTTP request to which calls the PHP function.  Then make an Ajax request to that script's URL.